# Bilinear inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $ x_1\in \mathbb{R^+}, y_1\in \mathbb{R^+}$, where $x_1 y_1 \ge c$. Also   $x_2 \in \mathbb{R^+}, y_2 \in \mathbb{R^+}$, $x_2 y_2 \ge c$.

I am trying to prove that $(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})(\frac{y_1 +y_2}{2}) \ge c$.  Any ideas?

This in **not** a homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM,
$$
\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)\left(\frac{y_1 +y_2}{2}\right)
\ge \sqrt{x_1 x_2} \sqrt{y_1 y_2}
= \sqrt{x_1 y_1} \sqrt{x_2 y_2}
\ge \sqrt{c}\sqrt{c} = c.
$$